# How toGet data from api and save it into local database sqlite then show in listview (from local)

Tags: flutter, api, sqlite, local-storage

How to get data from api and save the data to locally database sqlite?
this is my code, but still got error in dio
can you guys help me

[error dio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5Vbi.png)

```
import 'package:bloggggg/employee_model.dart';
import 'package:bloggggg/db_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

class EmployeeApiProvider {
  Future<List<Employee?>> getAllEmployees() async {
    final url = "http://demo8161595.mockable.io/employee";
    Response response = await Dio().get(url);

    if(response.statusCode == 200){
      return (response.data as List).map((employee) {
        print('Inserting $employee');
        DBProvider.db.createEmployee(Employee.fromJson(employee));
      }).toList();
    }else{
      return response.data;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't share screenshots or images of the code or errors. Kindly update your question properly with [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and what you have tried so far

Answer (score 1):

Save Api Data Function

```
save() async {
          final dbHelper = DatabaseHelper.instance;
          const url = "http://demo8161595.mockable.io/employee";
          final result = await get(Uri.parse(url));
          final response = jsonDecode(result.body);
          Map<String, dynamic> row = DatabaseInsetItemModel(
                  name: response["name"] ?? "",
                  lName: response["lName"] ?? "",
                  mobile: response["mobile"] ?? "",
                  email: response["email"] ?? "",
                  cat: response["cat"] ?? "",
                  profile: response["profile"] ?? "")
              .toJson();
          print('insert stRT');

          final id = await dbHelper.insertContact(row);
          if (kDebugMode) {
            print('inserted row id: $id');
          }
        }
```

DataBase Helper

```
class DatabaseHelper {
  static final _databaseName = "MyDatabase.db";
  static final _databaseVersion = 1;

  static final table = 'category';
  static final tableContact = 'contact';

  static final columnId = '_id';
  static final columnName = 'name';
  static final columnLName = 'lname';
  static final columnMobile = 'mobile';
  static final columnEmail = 'email';
  static final columnCategory = 'cat';
  static final columnProfile = 'profile';

  // make this a singleton class
  DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();
  static final DatabaseHelper instance = DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();

  // only have a single app-wide reference to the database
  static Database? _database;
  Future<Database> get database async => _database ??= await _initDatabase();
  Future<Database?> get database1 async {
    if (_database == null) {
      _database = await _initDatabase();
    }
    return _database;
  }

  // this opens the database (and creates it if it doesn't exist)
  _initDatabase() async {
    Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, _databaseName);
    return await openDatabase(path,
        version: _databaseVersion, onCreate: _onCreate);
  }

  // SQL code to create the database table
  Future _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute('''
          CREATE TABLE $table (
            $columnId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
            $columnName TEXT NOT NULL 
          )
          ''');
    await db.execute('''
          CREATE TABLE $tableContact (
            $columnId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
            $columnName TEXT NOT NULL, 
            $columnLName TEXT NOT NULL, 
            $columnMobile TEXT NOT NULL, 
            $columnEmail TEXT NOT NULL, 
            $columnCategory TEXT NOT NULL, 
            $columnProfile TEXT NOT NULL
          )
          ''');
  }

  // Helper methods

  // Inserts a row in the database where each key in the Map is a column name
  // and the value is the column value. The return value is the id of the
  // inserted row.
  Future<int> insert(Map<String, dynamic> row) async {
    Database? db = await instance.database;
    return await db.insert(table, row);
  }

  Future<int> insertContact(Map<String, dynamic> row) async {
    Database? db = await instance.database;
    return await db.insert(tableContact, row);
  }

  // All of the rows are returned as a list of maps, where each map is
  // a key-value list of columns.
  Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> queryAllRows() async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    return await db.query(table);
  }

  Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> queryAllRowsofContact() async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    return await db.query(tableContact);
  }

  // All of the methods (insert, query, update, delete) can also be done using
  // raw SQL commands. This method uses a raw query to give the row count.
  Future<int> queryRowCount() async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    return Sqflite.firstIntValue(
        await db.rawQuery('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table')) ??
        0;
  }

  // We are assuming here that the id column in the map is set. The other
  // column values will be used to update the row.
  Future<int> update(Map<String, dynamic> row) async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    int id = row[columnId];
    return await db.update(table, row, where: '$columnId = ?', whereArgs: [id]);
  }

  // Deletes the row specified by the id. The number of affected rows is
  // returned. This should be 1 as long as the row exists.
  Future<int> delete(int id) async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    return await db.delete(table, where: '$columnId = ?', whereArgs: [id]);
  }

  Future<int> deleteContact(int id) async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    return await db.delete(tableContact, where: '$columnId = ?', whereArgs: [id]);
  }
}
```

DataBase Item Model

```
    class DatabaseInsetItemModel{
  String? name;
  String? lName;
  String? mobile;
  String? email;
  String? cat;
  String? profile;

  DatabaseInsetItemModel(
      {required this.name, required this.lName, required this.mobile, required this.email, required this.cat, required this.profile});
  DatabaseInsetItemModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    name = json['postId'];
    lName = json['id'];
    mobile = json['name'];
    email = json['email'];
    cat = json['body'];
    profile = json['body'];

  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data[DatabaseHelper.columnName] = name;
    data[DatabaseHelper.columnLName] = lName;
    data[DatabaseHelper.columnMobile] = mobile;
    data[DatabaseHelper.columnEmail] = email;
    data[DatabaseHelper.columnCategory] = cat;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Show Data on screen

```
class ShowPostScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  ShowPostScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ShowPostScreen> createState() => _ShowPostScreenState();
}

class _ShowPostScreenState extends State<ShowPostScreen> {
  final dbHelper = DatabaseHelper.instance;
  List<DatabaseInsetItemModel> data = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
      dbHelper.queryAllRows().then((value) {
  setState(() {
    data = value.map((e) => DatabaseInsetItemModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
  });
});
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: data.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Text(data[index].name ?? "");
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```